# Les significations de l'adverbe de lieu « là »

Tags: adverbes

J'entends souvent l'adverbe « là » utilisé dans des échanges, cependant je me demande quelles sont les significations de cet adverbe.

Parmi exemples que j'entends:

- J'ai croisé une fille dans la rue et là a commencé mon histoire avec elle.
- J'ai réussi à le convaincre et là, on s'est mis d'accord au sujet de financer mon entreprise.
- Tu fais quoi maintenant ? là, je suis en train de cuisiner mon déjeuner.
- Si tu arrives à apprendre la grammaire, la conjugaison, l'orthographe le vocabulaire, là tu auras un bon niveau en français.

J'ai l'impression que dans la langue argotique, "là" devient un simple articulateur, qui pourrait être employé par tous et pas seulement pour exprimer le lieu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I** "Là" est un adverbe de lieu et moins souvent un adverbe de temps.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A0)) **I** Adv. Adverbe de lieu (plus rarement de temps) marquant le lieu où se trouve le locuteur ou un lieu plus ou moins éloigné de lui.

Dans vos phrases la troisième « là » figure en tant qu'adverbe de temps : c'est ainsi parce que la question comprend le mot « maintenant », qui est un adverbe de temps.
 It means "maintenant", "en ce moment".

- 3/ Tu fais quoi maintenant ? là/maintenant/en ce moment, je suis en train de cuisiner mon déjeuner.

Si au lieu de « maintenant » on avait eu « là » (Qu'est-ce que tu fait là ?) il y aurait eu deux possibilités : le temps comme ci-dessus ou le renforcement par un explétif, selon le contexte.

> ) [Avec une valeur simplement expressive, sert de particule explétive de renforcement, pour renvoyer à une phrase, à une circonstance désignée par le contexte]

La notion que « là » est un explétif trouve aisément sa justification en cela que au lieu de répondre « Là je suis en train de cuisiner mon déjeuner. » on peut dire « Je suis en train de cuisiner mon déjeuner. ».

Par exemple si la personne qui demande voit l'autre personne s'activant à sortir des casseroles et des aliments, et que ce sont ces actions qui la laisse dans l'incertitude (réarrangement, cuisine, cuisine pour le moment présent ou cuisine pour un autre jour, etc.) l'utilisation de « là » sera le moyen pour signifier à l'autre que la question porte sur les circonstances de cette activité. Il n'y a pas d'ambiguïté.

**II** Un autre ensemble d'usage consiste des usages du type dit référentiel.
 Dans le type de ceux où « là » est employé seul, on trouve l'usage qu'il en est fait dans les phrases « 1 », « 2 » et « 4 ».

> B. − Emploi référentiel
>   1. [Employé seul]
>   d) P. anal., avec valeur temporelle
>   α) À ce moment-là. Synon. alors

- 1/ J'ai croisé une fille dans la rue et [là/alors/à ce moment-là] a commencé mon histoire avec elle.
- 2/ J'ai réussi à le convaincre et [là/alors/à ce moment-là], on s'est mis d'accord sur le point de financer mon entreprise.
- 4/ Si tu arrives à apprendre la grammaire, la conjugaison, l'orthographe le vocabulaire, [là/alors/à ce moment-là] tu auras un bon niveau en français.

**III** Par articulateur, qui ne désigne en français qu'un « Organe qui participe activement à l'émission des sons de la parole (les lèvres, la langue, les alvéoles, le voile du palais, etc.) », selon le Larousse, je suppose que vous voulez dire « filler ». Non, je ne crois pas qu'il s'agisse d'un tel processus ni d'une tendance argotique. Il s'agirait plutôt d'une tendance à parler sans recherche, facilement, et plus rapidement aussi, et au lieu d'identifier les circonstances ou de les identifier de nouveau d'utiliser un court terme référentiel.

Exemple : deux personnes s'approchant d'un à-pic profond

— Là je ne vais pas pouvoir avancer plus près. (*circonstances de proximité*)
— Là je n'ai pas peur.  (*mêmes circonstances de  proximité*)
— Et là (lui mettant les mains sur les yeux) ?  (*mêmes circonstances de  proximité avec un élément en plus*)
— Là non plus, je te connais.  (*comme précédemment*)
— Là tu crois être en sécurité ?  (*comme précédemment mais un élément en plus*)
— Là, oui!  (*comme précédemment*)

Il y a évidemment dans ce dialogue une abondance d'occurrences de l'adverbe « là » qui le rend quelque peu étrange, de plus qu'il est de ce fait moins explicite, mais il n'est pas question d'argot ni de remplissage, et il n'y aurait à voir en cela qu'une qualité médiocre du langage qui reste du langage standard. À la cinquième ligne il devient peu explicite, on devine plus que l'on ne comprend.

Comment: Merci beaucoup @LPH j'apprècie énormement letemp que vous avez consacré pour répondre à ma question, maintenant je comprends vraiment mieux les différents utilisations

Answer (score 2):

Les exemples cités indiquent que la fonction spatiale de "là" a été étendue à une fonction temporelle (signification: "à un moment donné").